# How to save the content of a tab in Dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

The problem is,
Imagine we have x amount of tabs, where we start at tab1.

Let's say we load some data and a graph is then updated.

Then we go to tab2, and then back to tab1.

Now tab1 is using it's default layout and the graph is not showing with the loaded data anymore.

How to keep tabs in the same state? Any working examples of this?

My app is now build, so it has an index.py that changes layout depending of which tab is chosen, loading the layout from other files.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like what you want is to render the tab content as children. Check out the [docs](https://dash.plot.ly/dash-core-components/tabs) for a section that explains how to set that up. Essentially, each tab will be independent of the others, so once the data is loaded for a tab it will stay that way until you change it through a callback for the children of that tab, or the components in the `children` prop.

Comment: if you define the graph then the children will work but for dynamic plotting using callback it will not work also,